# How to set game score using setGameScore in python telegram bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I'm using BOT API for telegram,

through **setGameScore** i tried to set game score of user with _user_id_ and *score* but its not working ...
used **bot.setGameScore (user_id = 56443156,score=65)**

**Iam not using game to set only for inlinequery**

i received a  **caused error :** "**Message to set game score not found**"

Answer (score 0):

Used :

**bot.setGameScore (user_id = 5432131, score=76,inline_message_id=uygrtfghfxGKJB)**

I received these two(**user_id,inline_message_id**)  parameters  from **update.callback_query**